# PHP CLI application debug in ZendStudio (STDIN)

Tags: php, debugging, stdin, command-line-interface, zend-studio

0

I am trying to debug php CLI using Zend Studio. My problem: I can't get user input from keyboard.

This is part of code (method in some class):

```
public function getInput($promt = null, $defaultValue = null) {
    if(!isset($promt)){
        $promt = self::$DEFAULT_PROMPT;
    }
    echo $promt;
    $stdin = fopen ( "php://stdin", "r" );  
    $val = fgets ( $stdin );
    return $val;
}
```

So ZS walks through code quite ok, but it stops at $val=fgets() And I have no clue where am I supposed to enter something from keyboard. I tried in console, and everywhere, I chacked debug configuration (Allocate console = on) etc.

HELP!

Comment: Have you tried "echo foo | program" just to see what's going on?

Comment: From what I've found so far, the fopen() is causing the debug session to hang, as it's treating the process as a stream. I've not figured out how to force an EOF marker or a way to truncate the stream yet.

Comment: echo works quite ok.
the problem is how to get input.
Seems ZS does not support typing in the console at all, so fopen(STDIN) hangs.